# CruiseControl.Net: How Does One Clear Obsolete Build History?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I just started using CCNet, and in the process of getting my build projects set up I racked up a lot of build history from trial and error. I really don't want to keep that old stuff around, but I can't seem to see where/how to get rid of it. I'm sure this is a silly question, and I apologize if I'm overlooking something that should be obvious. I did [RTM](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Documentation) and Google for about a half hour, and poked around my CCNet installation, but it's not jumping out at me. I deleted the state files for the projects (don't know if that has anything to do with it), but the old builds are still there if I drill into a project's stats from the dashboard. Any suggestions? Thanks.

**Answered**: I had explicitly set the artifacts directory to a location that was not under the CCNet server directory and consequently never looked in it again... went looking and, disco, there's the build histories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a project called "Dev" and you've installed CCNet into the default location, you'll have a folder called:

c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\Dev

and a Dev.state file in:

c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server

Just delete both the folder and the state file.

Comment: Doh! I had explicitly set the artifacts directory to a location that was not under the CCNet server directory and consequently never looked in it again... went looking and, disco, there's the build histories.

Comment: This might be slightly out of date - I found no "Dev" folder under ..\server\. It was sufficient to:
1) stop the cruisecontrol.net service
2) delete the Dev.state file
3) restart the service
4) force a build to eliminate the "Unknown" Last build time.

Answer (score 11):

Don't forget you can use [Artifact Cleanup Publisher](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Artifact_Cleanup_Publisher) to keep your build history from growing to the size of Mars over time.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer, because deleting the entire folder differs from smart cleaning, which this publisher actually does.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for are the "artifacts" folders.  Check your ccnet.config file for the tag

Stop your service, delete the artifact directory folder, and restart your service.

Answer (score 1):

The logs are stored in the artifacts directories under artifacts\MyProjectName\Build\log*.xml.

The State file stores things like the last build date, time, info.

Best to stop the service, and then delete the *.state in ProgFiles\CC.net\server and also delete the artifacts\MyProjectName\Build\log*.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, use the Artifact Cleanup Publisher to keep the number of artifacts to a sensible level.

If you have a lot of projects and need to do a retrospective cleanup, you could use the following Powershell script to remove old log files:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

get-childitem -Path D:\Builds -filter MatchMyProjects.* | %{ 
    $projectPath=$_.FullName
    $logsPath=$projectPath + "\Logs"    
    write-host Removing logs from folder $logsPath
    Get-ChildItem -Path $logsPath -Force -Filter *.xml | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Thanks to this answer: [Delete files older than 15 days using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829785/delete-files-older-than-15-days-using-powershell)