# Intel RCS Logging

Tags: windows, intel

I've recently set up Intel RCS to provision AMT 9.0 machines, however during the process I didn't come across any mention of logging/configuring the log levels. After about 3 weeks of running, the box ended up filling up with over 30gb of 1mb log files.

I haven't been able to locate anything in the Intel documentation regarding logfile configuration.

I'm thinking of running a PS script to just delete old logfiles, however I would much rather modify the configuration of the program itself.

This is what I'm thinking of using as a last resort.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Intel_Corporation\RCSConfServer" -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: As of AMT 8.0, the Audit Log is enabled automatically.  I'm going to poke around a bit and see if there is a threshold you can set so it will clear automatically or if you can disable it without reprovisioning. You can read about it in the AMT SDK Reference Guide.  Search for Audit Log. https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/HTMLDocuments/WS-Management_Class_Reference/AMT_AuditLog.htm#RequestStateChange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the same issue recently as well. We had some database issues that hadn't resolved themselves over the weekend, in turn causing a massive influx of 1074kb logfiles (my count was roughly 25,000)

I'm doing something similar on a weekly basis, just incase any new information appears.

I'd recommend checking [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829785/delete-files-older-than-15days-using-powershell) as it provides a fair bit of info on deleting files.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I'm not the only one in this situation. I'll trial this and see if it helps. Interesting that Intel hasn't provided any log control....

Comment: Yeah, I'll post back if I find anything, but I think the RCS console is more for AMT Configuration than actually modifying the application.