# Powershell script to delete by date and file name

Tags: shell, powershell, filenames, delete-file

I know this question has been asked several times, but I'm having issues getting it working. I'm a noob when it comes to programming so borrowing code is about the most I can do. I need a script that can delete files that are in a folder that are X days old, but also need to only delete ones that contain "XXX" in the file names. They have no file extensions. I've seen a couple scripts on here that delete by date, and/or file extension but cant seem to get it working where it looks for certain characters. If anyone could help me out I would forever be in your debt.

Comment: Thought about renting a coder?

Answer (score 2):

This may be one of the questions that you viewed: [Delete files older than 15 days using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829785/delete-files-older-than-15-days-using-powershell)

If you use one of the listed solutions that uses `Get-ChildItem` to get files of a specified age, add `-Filter *XXX*` to the `Get-ChildItem` command to limit the results to files that contain "XXX" in the file name.

Comment: I did see that script but Im having issues getting that one to delete any files that are not set to 0 days. The files have a date modified of 2011 so they plenty old enough for the script. Im moving the files to a new folder for testing but they are not deleting, with just that script.