# Copy-Item script creating files on google drive that I cannot delete

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a new folder on google drive and append the date and hour to the end of it to create a rolling 1 hour backup with old versions still accessible. I am not knowledgeable enough about PowerShell in order to automatically delete folders over 7 days old so I have to do it manually. The problem seems to be when PowerShell creates the new folders and copies the files, I no longer have access to delete them. I have checked permissions and added Everyone, Administrators, and the current user (the only user and admin) and it still will not allow me to delete the folders that PowerShell creates. I can delete files I manually put into Google drive. Here is my code:

```
$yest = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString(‘hhMMddyy’)
mkdir "C:\Users\admin\Google Drive\SpaceEngineersDedicated.$yest" -Force
Copy-Item C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\SpaceEngineersDedicated -Destination "C:\Users\admin\Google Drive\SpaceEngineersDedicated.$yest" -Recurse -Force
```

If someone could help me with code that will just delete folders over 7 days, I would appreciate it but worst case scenario I'm fine with occasionally cleaning them up manually.

Comment: What do you mean "have no longer access to delete them"? You didn't show any code that'd delete something. Did you try `Remove-Item` on a folder? Do you get errors? What do they say?

Comment: I'm talking about manual deletion of the files copied. Something about this script is messing up the permissions in a way that I can't seem to understand. It says the owner is the 1 and only user on the system but it gives me the famous windows message "you need permission to perform this action"

Comment: Check if something is still keeping an open handle to that folder (with [`handle`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) or [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete files older than 15 days using PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829785/delete-files-older-than-15-days-using-powershell)