# A script to archive all files last modified dated a specific month-year

Tags: powershell, command-line, archive, 7zip

I need to create a script (or command line) that will utilise 7-zip and archive all files dated a specific month-date. e.g. compress and archive all files in a specified directory that are date modified xx-may-2018 and create the archive in another specified directory.

There are plenty of scripts around for archiving but none that allow you to specify month-year.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: There are several questions about how to [delete files older than](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17829785) a date. Can you adapt such a logic into archiving script?