# '$limit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: powershell

i am currently trying to clean up some folders and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829785/delete-files-older-than-15-days-using-powershell/19326146#19326146) which seems to be just the thing i was looking for.

So i modified the limit, opened powershell and navigated to the desired folder and executed the .bat. Unfortunately i get the following message:

```
PS Z:\merle\Backup_HPLaptop\Manuel_01042023\FileHistory> .\powershell-delet_ding.bat

Z:\merle\Backup_HPLaptop\Manuel_01042023\FileHistory>$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
'$limit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Z:\merle\Backup_HPLaptop\Manuel_01042023\FileHistory>$path = 'Z:\merle\Backup_HPLaptop\Manuel_01042023\FileHistory'
'$path' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Z:\merle\Backup_HPLaptop\Manuel_01042023\FileHistory># Delete files older than the $limit.
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Z:\merle\Backup_HPLaptop\Manuel_01042023\FileHistory>Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force   | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }   | Remove-Item -Force
'Get-ChildItem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have no idea why this isnt working since it is designed for powershell? Thanks!

I tried googling the error but it seems to be associated with paths ususally

Comment: Save your code as `.ps1` instead of `.bat` and run as  `.\powershell-delet_ding.ps1`. (BTW, you could do `Rename-Item .\powershell-delet_ding.bat powershell-delet_ding.ps1` once).